# Unit testing a MvvmCross.Droid.View

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I need to confirm the behaviour of a button via a unit test within a Android and an iOS view.

For the Android view; I have a view which inherits from MvxActivity.  My iOS view inherits from MvxViewController.

If we take the Android view for instance; I have the button's click event bound like so:

```
_buttonUseVideo.Click += DisableButton;
```

And the event handler looks like this:

```
private void DisableButton(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _button.Enabled = false;
    _localViewModel.Close();
}
```

I cannot use an acceptance test because the form immediately closes after I click the button.  Is it possible to test this behaviour via a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam not sure if a UnitTest is the right answer here for you, atleast if you want to keep the implementation that way.

If you want to test UI-Elements you should use a UITest for Xamarin (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/), where you could to things like this and let the test do all needed user interactions beforehand:

```
var isDrawerOpen = app.Query(d => d.Id("navigation_drawer").Invoke("isDrawerOpen", 3));
    Assert.True((bool) isDrawerOpen[0]);
```

Another option would be to remove the eventhandler and the `_button.Enabled = false` to replace it with MVVMCross Bindings. So you could fully ignore the view and just use the unittest for your viewmodel.

Though it wouldnt make much sense to test if the button is disabled just before the ViewModel is closed in my opinion. Or is there more happening with the button or the viewmodel.close() that you didnt share with us?